# What syntax for of a Java regexp must be used to catch the near last part of a line (details in post)?

Tags: java, regex, file-io

I must apologize beforehand as this is most likely a very silly conceptual mistake on my part but i am stuck with a regexp to match a line in an in/out-put file, the line would read:

random stuff 123.4: {OR} random stuff 1234.5

I want to do the following to that line:

```
while ((c_line = c_reader.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println("Entering RegExp loop\n");
String regline1 = "\.\\d{3}\.\\d\\:";
   if (c_line.endsWith (regline1)) {
       /* read value and next few lines into buffer */
   }
}
```

If i am not mistaking my regexp should match [Any character] (this to make sure i catch both the 3 and 4 digit values (before the comma) -> [3 digits], literal [.] and again [digit]. Sadly i can't get this matching to do what i am expecting however.

If Anyone can tell me where i am making the (conceptual) mistake, that would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Bas Jansen

Comment: Could you post some input lines examples?

Comment: The first problem is that `String.endsWith` does not take a regular expression but the absolute string you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method of the String class looks for a ***string and not a pattern*** at the end of another string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, i was worried i was making a conceptual mistake already as i apparently was :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\d{3,4}\\.\\d:$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(c_line);
if (matcher.matches()){
   ...
}
```

Note the `$` at the end of the regex to specify that the match must occur at the end of the input string.

Comment: The colon is optional, so the regex should be `.*\\d{3,4}\\.\\d[:]?$`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can use any of the RegEx helpers [listed here](http://www.moskalyuk.com/blog/regular-expression-helpers) to help you narrow down problems with your expressions.